# Accessing ASP.Net WebService using XMLHttpRequest and SOAP

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

I have a webService hosted at http://recpushdata.cyndigo.com/jobs.asmx. I would like to call this webservice using XMLHttpRequest and SOAP. The thing why I would like to do this is that I have hosted a client application which is accessing the webservice perfectly, but when client is trying to access the same webservice its giving some error like :-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
- <soap:Body>
- <soap:Fault>
  <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode> 
  <faultstring>Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</faultstring> 
  <detail /> 
  </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

Which unfortunately I am not able to figure out?

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/kaevans/archive/2007/04/27/a-nostalgic-look-at-using-xmlhttprequest-with-soap.aspx). But XmlHttpRequest and SOAP are *painful* as you have construct SOAP bodies manually.